# Debian 5.0.8 won't detect my ethernet adapter

Tags: linux, installation, drivers, debian, ethernet

I'm installing Debian 5.0.8 on a Dell Latitude E6410 using the network install x86 CD.

Unfortunately, it won't detect my Ethernet adapter. Specifically, I get the error: `No Ethernet card was detected. If you know the name of the driver needed by your Ethernet card, you can select it from the list.`

lspci shows: `00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 10ea (rev 05)`

That should correspond to the e1000e driver. But, if I select it from the list, the install CD still fails to detect it.

Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows 7 are able to use this device with no problem.

Does anybody know what I can do to make Debian use/recognize my ethernet adapter?

---

**Edit:** Additional Info:

- I think this is an Intel 82577LM Gigabit Ethernet chipset.
- If I switch from the graphical installer to the console and run `lsmod`, I see `e1000e` with a use count of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

82577LM support was added to the linux kernel in 2.6.31, so Debian 5.0.8 will not support it.

You can either use an unofficial unsupported installer image such as [kmuto](http://kmuto.jp/debian/d-i/), that includes a newer kernel and firmware for certain hardware.

Or you can install [Debian 6.0 Release Candidate 2](http://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/) (or wait less than a week for the official release). I highly recommend going with Debian 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

The answer (for anybody else in this mess) is to:

1. install from the regular install CD. (not the net installer).
2. install the linux-headers, make, and gcc development packages.
3. Go to intel.com and [download](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=15817&ProdId=3244&lang=eng) the latest ethernet drivers. (from another PC that has working ethernet, obviously)
4. Copy those drivers via thumb-drive to the debian PC and install them following the instructions in the included readme.

Now, the ethernet is working.